# HTML to return current month and year & Previous month and year

Tags: html

I am trying to update some html text to be dynamic and update to show the current year and month and one to show the previous year and month.

I currently am typing it out manually in the HTML editor (No code just text)

Current Cycle: August 2022 [ WIP ]

Previous Cycle: July 2022 [ WIP ]

I am trying to get this exact output that will update to reflect the current and previous month as well as the year. I would think it would be some combination of getDate() then convert to month and add the getYear() to the end, but cant figure it out.

Comment: code sample please

Comment: There isnt any code written for it currently, it is using a HTML overlay so i can just type out each title

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the date from the browser we can get the current month, previous month and the current year to display the needed info on the page. Here's a live example:

> **Caution:** the method `getMonth` of the `Date` object is 0 based where the index 0 is the first month of the year (which is January).

```js
const currentCycle = document.getElementById('current-cycle'),
  previousCycle = document.getElementById('previous-cycle'),
  // a map to convert index based months to their names. Remeber "getMonth" is zero-based so 0 means January
  monthsToStr = {
    0: 'January',
    1: 'February',
    2: 'Mars',
    3: 'April',
    4: 'May',
    5: 'June',
    6: 'July',
    7: 'August',
    8: 'September',
    9: 'October',
    10: 'November',
    11: 'December',
  },
  currentDate = new Date(),
  [currentMonth, currentYear] = [currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getFullYear()],
  // return the formated text based on the month and the year
  formatText = (month, year) => monthsToStr[month] + ' ' + year;

// display the month and date info on the page
currentCycle.textContent = formatText(currentMonth, currentYear);
// here we pass "currentMonth - 1" to get the previous month index
previousCycle.textContent = formatText(currentMonth - 1, currentYear);
```

```html
<p>Current Cycle: <b id="current-cycle"></b></p>
<p>Previous Cycle: <b id="previous-cycle"></b></p>
```

> Learn more about [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object on MDN.

> Learn more about [`getMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) method on MDN.

> Learn more about [`getFullYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) method on MDN.